# Difference between .pack() and .place() and using them together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What is the primary difference between these two functions?

I'm currently working on a program that contains a canvas and a label, the latter is behaving as a button. Now the canvas was placed using .pack() while I used .place() for the label. Additionally the program reads and uses the location of mouse clicks to perform certain actions.

There is currently a bug that causes the program to trigger an unexpected action upon clicking the label, to my surprise upon clicking the label the x and y coordinate of the mouse click are not in reference to the window (as I expected it to be) but rather to the top-left coordinates of the label.

Is there a way to set it so that the label does not modify the x and y coordinate of the mouse click within it?

I'm relatively new to python and this is the first projects I've made using tkinter. If needed I can provide the code upon request.

**EDIT:** Entire program can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/hMjWhfQF). Labels are added starting at line 87:

```
      newgame_Label = Label(parent, anchor=NW, font="Calibri",
           text="New Game")
      newgame_Label.bind("<Button 1>", self.newgame_Click)      
      newgame_Label.place(x=450, y=300)

      reset_Label = Label(parent, anchor=NW, font="Calibri",
           text="Reset Board")
      reset_Label.bind("<Button 1>", self.reset_Click)      
      reset_Label.place(x=450, y=400)
```

The function initBoard calls the .pack() method on the canvas. The program is a clone of [Light's Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29), thought it would be a good way of learning python and tkinter.

Alternately I can just not use a label and simply use the create_text method available to a canvas widget, but this would require some workaround to determine if it has been clicked. Mostly interested in finding out why is it that .place() for a Label Widget behaves the way it does event though they share the same frame.

Comment: First: can you show us your code? Second: you should definitely use `grid` geometry manager: [GRID](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) for this simple case.

Comment: Added, check edit. If I decide to use grid will I be able to overlap a canvas and label without any problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary difference is that `place` lets you specify absolute coordinates, and `pack` uses a box model which allows you to place widgets along the sides of the box.

place is not used that often in real world applications. It's great for a very small class of problems, but pack and grid are more useful. Place requires that you spend a lot more effort making the GUI resize properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pack() and place() together :

```
r = Tk()
label = Label(r, text = any text)
label.pack()
label.place(x = x, y = y)
```

Remember !
You must use pack before place